# Select command for cloudera impala to convert hexadecimal to ip address

Tags: sql, impala

I need select statement format for cloudera impala to convert hexadecimal to ip address.

Suppose a hexadecimal number is given (as shown below). How to convert it into impala with select statement like:-

> A.59.FC.6

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in Hive using `split` to split your string and `conv` to convert from base 16 to base 10; unfortunately although Impala does support `conv`, it doesn't seem that Impala has a `split` UDF built in, so if you're stuck with Impala you might have to write your own :(

**Hive code**:

```
 select concat(
           cast(conv(split(ipcolumn,'[.]')[0],16,10) as string), '.',
           cast(conv(split(ipcolumn,'[.]')[1],16,10) as string), '.',
           cast(conv(split(ipcolumn,'[.]')[2],16,10) as string), '.',
           cast(conv(split(ipcolumn,'[.]')[3],16,10) as string)
          )      
 from mytable;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. If i want to convert :- 0A59FB05 to ip address. Then, what is the syntax for this?

Comment: this you can do in impala; use `substr` to select out the different 2-letter components, then just modify the code above